# mlt: image distortion using lossless codec

Tags: mlt

I have two 1920x1080 PNG files, [center.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxCTc.png) and [right.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DETjR.png), which are identical except that the image in `right.png` is shifted horizontally by 325 pixels.

With mlt XML, I made a two-second long video using the lossless FFV1 format, showing one second of `center.png`, and then one second of `right.png`.  Here's my file, `foo.mlt`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>                                           
<mlt>                                                                            
  <profile width="1920" height="1080"                                            
           display_aspect_num="1920" display_aspect_den="1080"                   
           sample_aspect_num="1" sample_aspect_den="1"                           
           colorspace="709" progressive="1"                                      
           frame_rate_num="30" frame_rate_den="1"/>                              
                                                                                 
  <consumer mlt_service="avformat" properties="lossless/FFV1" target="out.mkv"/> 
                                                                                 
  <producer id="center" mlt_service="qimage" resource="center.png" length="30"/> 
  <producer id="right"  mlt_service="qimage" resource="right.png"  length="30"/> 
                                                                                 
  <playlist>                                                                     
    <entry producer="center"/>                                                   
    <entry producer="right"/>                                                    
  </playlist>                                                                    
</mlt>
```

Then I run `melt foo.mlt` at the terminal and check the output file `out.mkv` in my video viewer.  However, on close inspection, when `right.png` appears in the video, it is slightly distorted (with some sort of halo-type artifact).  Here is a magnified view:

[image]

Weirdly, only the `right.png` image is distorted; the `center.png` displays correctly, even though the two images are identical except for positioning.

Is this a bug?  I wouldn't expect any image distortion with a lossless codec, but maybe I've done something wrong.

My specs:

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, 64-bit
melt 6.25.0
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Lossless" is not always lossless. In the case of "lossless/FFV1", the chroma format is 4:2:2 which will cut the chroma resolution in half:
https://github.com/mltframework/mlt/blob/master/presets/consumer/avformat/lossless/FFV1
This could be relevant because if format conversion is required, it could cause chroma bleeding on pixels that do not land directly on a chroma sample.

As an experiment, you could try shifting the image by 326 pixels instead of 325 to see if the bleeding still occurs.

There was another question a while back that related to bleeding due to chroma subsampling:
[Melt composite transition is slightly blending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61437667/melt-composite-transition-is-slightly-blending/61471197)